# Does snowflake perform predicate pushdown when the clause is on a column from another table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization

I have a very large table in Snowflake (100b records) with columns

| eventDate | eventTypeId |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

I created a view by joining it with a small table (200 records) of the form

| eventTypeId | eventTypeName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'pay' |
| 2 | 'cancel' |
| 3 | 'loggin' |
| ... | ... |

To create a table of the form:

| eventDate | eventTypeId | eventTypeName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | 3 | 'login' |
| ... | ... | ... |

And now I'm looking to query the view with

```
SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE eventTypeName  = 'loggin'
```

However, I'm not seeing this predicate get pushed down to the original big table.

Does Snowflake support this?

Comment: Any idea why you don't want to push the predicate in the view to the table ?  one way you could is to create a Snowflake Materialized view,  don't know if it is a good approach.

Comment: The query optimiser will determine the most efficient way of executing the query. Is there something in the query profile that makes you think the query is not being executed in the most optimal way and, if there is, can you update your question with the query/explain plan and with what you think it should be doing that would be more efficient?

Comment: What happens if you only run the select portion of the query that creates the view, but with where clause added in? Do you see the predicate being pushed down?

Comment: The optimizer will almost certainly implement this as a join filter on the big table before going into the join. In the Query Profiler the join filter does not give a lot of information, but in this case it should do what's called a range filter on the keys with an eventTypeId min of 3 and a max of 3. As others have stated, the explain plan will help to determine what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I'd accept that as an answer if you add it.